# android facebook application

Tags: android, facebook, session

I'm trying to create on android a facebook application  and I'm using android `facebook-sdk` .
The example that I'm trying to understand is this one:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/stream

There is something that I don't understand in here if u could help me out a little bit it would be great.

At some point in the main `Activity` is doing something like:

```
 Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(this);
        dispatcher.addHandler("login", LoginHandler.class);
        dispatcher.addHandler("stream", StreamHandler.class);
        dispatcher.addHandler("logout", LogoutHandler.class);


        Session session = Session.restore(this);
        if (session != null) {
            dispatcher.runHandler("stream");
        } else {
            dispatcher.runHandler("login");
        }
    }
```

What I don't understand is the way this `Session.restore(this)` works.

The `restore` method looks like this:

```
public static Session restore(Context context) {
        if (singleton != null) {
            if (singleton.getFb().isSessionValid()) {
                return singleton;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs =
            context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String appId = prefs.getString(APP_ID, null);

        if (appId == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Facebook fb = new Facebook(appId);
        fb.setAccessToken(prefs.getString(TOKEN, null));
        fb.setAccessExpires(prefs.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        String uid = prefs.getString(UID, null);
        String name = prefs.getString(NAME, null);
        if (!fb.isSessionValid() || uid == null || name == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Session session = new Session(fb, uid, name);
        singleton = session;
        return session;
    }
```

If someone could explain me what is the whole purpose of `SharedPreferences`, what is stored there and why are these 2 lines needed :

```
 fb.setAccessToken(prefs.getString(TOKEN, null));
            fb.setAccessExpires(prefs.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access any `facebook` user information or any other action which requires `permission` to be accessed as shown below. [image: Image from facebook, facebook Authentication dialog]. If the user press `Allow` button then A `Token` is inserted in their Database with the `user Id` , `your App Id` and the `validation time` (which may be unlimited) as well as the `Actions` you may perform (`e.g Access Info, Send Email, Access Posts, Post to Wall etc.`), that specific `Token` is returned to you and you save that `Token` to access the info and other action which are permitted against that token.
Whenever you make a request for any action they match that token, check validation and then see if that action is allowed by the user, if allowed you are granted to complete the action.

Comment: So when I press allow, I also save in SharedPreferences that TOKEN which I will be using for restoring the Session?And also who is UID and NAME?

Comment: When you press allow you save that Token to `SharedPreferences` for future use, whenever you made a `Facebook` object in any `Activity` every time `restore()` method is called to ensure that the session is valid or not. `UID` and `NAME` are the user's facebook Id and facebook name.